# java accessibility for nested panel inside a main panel in swing

Tags: java, swing

This is my first time using java accessibility for a swing application. Here is a brief code for drawing the swing application.  There are more code for the swing application, but i think that i just want to provide a outline of the layout. mainPanel has a title and a tree in the left side and a content panel in the right.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
// add title to the main panel

JList list = new JList();
// add list model which will be displayed in a tree.
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
mainPanel.add(scrollPane);

JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
// add components(radio buttons and some text fields) to the content panel
mainPanel.add(contentPanel);


JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
```

When the swing application is launched, i hear a voice reading title from the main panel and some radio buttons in the content panel, but I don't hear anything from the tree in the left side. The tree contains information about the installation step, but it doesn't read anything.

I am not sure if it is related to the code or a layout or a panel focus issue.

It would be great if someone who has done accessibility for swing has had a similar issue provides any tips or help.

Comment: Have you had a look at and of the documentation about `javax.swing.JList.AccessibleJList`?

Comment: It is my misunderstanding about the tree. it is not supposed to read all the list in the tree. it should read the first item by default, but it doesn't. I did 'panel.requestFocus()', but it still doesn't read the first item in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will be fine 
Add another panel to mainpanel

```
JPanel listPanel=createPanel();

JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
// add components(radio buttons and some text fields) to the content panel
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(listPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);

mainPanel.add(contentPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);

JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
mainFrame.add(mainPanel);


Then create a function 
private JPanel createPanel(){
JPanel listPanel=new JPanel();

JList list=new JList();

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
listPanel.add(scrollPane);
listPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
return listPanel;

}
```